# Clicking on anchor links moves whole page to top

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

So I have this webpage where the whole html's overflow is hidden

```
html {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

and then I have a nav bar that has anchor links and a div that has the content which has an overflow auto, thus it's scrollable.

Nav:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jazz">Jazz</a></li>
  <li><a href="#weddings">Weddings</a></li>
</ul>
```

Content div:

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="events">Events</div>
  // content
  <div id="jazz">Jazz</div>
  // content
  <div id="weddings">Weddings</div>
  // content
</div>
```

Now, my problem is when you click on a link on the nav, like for example jazz, the whole page just goes to the top, everything: the nav, the div content and obviously, the div shows the jazz section . Is there a way where everything just stays in place and the div content box just scrolls to a certain section?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are looking for is `event.preventDefault()` but am not answering because your details are insufficient

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I don't think he's looking for anything to do with javascript. It sounds like he's just after [HTML links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_links_bookmark). I Believe you just need to move your ID, eg: `<div><a id="events"></a>Events</div>`

Comment: @MLeFevre Nope, you don't move ids

Answer (score 2):

Just make content overflow: scroll; In this case scroll works for conteiner and not for html.

```
.content{
    /* */   
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

**Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/bvvhy6jj/**

Answer (score 1):

Given the information you provided I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. Or maybe I'm not understanding your question.

The following (which I built off your code) works the way you seem to want it to.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {overflow: hidden;}
        div#content {height: 1500px;}
        div#events {height: 500px;background-color: green;}
        div#jazz {height: 500px;background-color: red;}
        div#weddings {height: 500px;background-color: blue;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#jazz">Jazz</a></li>
      <li><a href="#weddings">Weddings</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="events">Events</div>
      // content
      <div id="jazz">Jazz</div>
      // content
      <div id="weddings">Weddings</div>
      // content
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Do you intend to pin the Navigation at the top of the window even when the user scrolls to lower content? If so see this [SMINT](http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/demo/) tutorial on how to build a one page site with a sticky navigation bar. And then buy him a coffee :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but might help you where you wanna get

http://jsfiddle.net/maximhash/8ts7qzj3/

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#events">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="#jazz">Jazz</a></li>
  <li><a href="#weddings">Weddings</a></li>
</ul>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="content">
  <div id="events">Events</div>
  <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
  <div id="jazz">Jazz</div>
  <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
  <div id="weddings">Weddings</div>
  <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>


#nav{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background: orange;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 500px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as far as i understand you want your navigation staying fixed. So you have to set it 'fixed' :

```
ul {
   position:fixed;
}
```